# Bin and aggregate with `seaborn.objects`

Tags: python, plot, seaborn, visualization, seaborn-0.12.x

Is there a way to both bin and aggregate (with some other function than `count`) in `seaborn.objects`? I'd like to compute the mean per bin and right now I'm using the following:

```py
import seaborn.objects as so
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
df2 = (
    df.groupby(pd.cut(df["bill_length_mm"], bins=30))[["bill_depth_mm"]]
    .mean()
)
df2["bill_length_mm"] = [x.mid for x in df2.index]
p = so.Plot(df2, x="bill_length_mm", y="bill_depth_mm").add(so.Bars())

p
```

Answer (score 3):

There's not yet a binning operation separate from `Hist` (this could make sense as a `Stat` or a `Scale`, I'm not sure).

But note that you can do the aggregation more simply than you are in your example because you can pass a Series directly and don't need to construct a new dataframe:

```
(
    so.Plot(
        df,
        x="bill_depth_mm",
        y=pd.cut(df["bill_length_mm"], bins=30).map(lambda x: x.mid),
    )
    .add(so.Bars(), so.Agg("mean"))
)
```

Note that the Series will be aligned with the DataFrame (or other Series passed directly) based on the index information rather than position.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! "Note that the Series will be aligned with the DataFrame (or other Series passed directly) based on the index information rather than position." ... I'm not sure what this means :)

Comment: e.g., `s1 = pd.Series([1, 2, 3], index=[*'ABC'])` and `s2 = pd.Series([1, 2, 3], index=[*'BCA'])` would align as 1:3, 2:1, 3:2 (based on `A`, `B`, `C`) rather than 1:1, 2:2, 3:3 (based on position in array)